# Как сделать рамку по углам блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вот такую рамку как на картинке?

[image: Рамка]

Рамка идёт по углам блока.
Пробовал задавать через `border: 10px dashed black`, но рамка идёт по всей границе блока.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением!

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after`. Например, так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  background: #066fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.block:before,
.block:after,
.border:before,
.border:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  content: '';
  border-color: #082346;
  border-style: solid;
}

.block:before {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 9px 0 0 9px;
}

.block:after {
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 9px 9px 0 0;
}

.border:before {
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-width: 0 9px 9px 0;
}

.border:after {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-width: 0 0 9px 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#content {position:relative;width:400px;height:300px;}
#content:before, #content:after, #content>:first-child:before, #content>:first-child:after {
    position:absolute;
    width:80px; height: 80px;
    border-color:black; 
    border-style:solid; 
    content: ' ';
}
#content:before {top:0;left:0;border-width: 3px 0 0 3px}
#content:after {top:0;right:0;border-width: 3px 3px 0 0}
#content>:first-child:before {bottom:0;right:0;border-width: 0 3px 3px 0}
#content>:first-child:after {bottom:0;left:0;border-width: 0 0 3px 3px}
.blue {
  background:blue;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"><div class="blue"></div></div>
```